# Eclipse layout changes

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I recently installed new C/C++ software plugins for Eclipse. After restart, the perspective changed. I didn't like the new colors and stuff, so I got rid of it via Preferences->General->Appereance->Restore Defaults.

There's only one thing left thats bugging me, it's really a minor issue but nevertheless I'd like to have it fixed. The project explorer went kinda smooth and round, before the changes it was edgy. Same with the tabs. Searched the web, couldn't find an answer. Anyone?

[Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kTUi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Toggle this setting within General Preferences:[image]

Comment: That does the trick, but then again it turns the toolbar background kinda blue-ish which I think is disguisting. I want it to look exactly like in my screenshot, just with edgy borders !